# Order by parent-child relation "ItemCode"-"ItemReplacementCode" in one table

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, select, group-by, sql-order-by

Let's suppose we have records of product with columns `ItemCode` and `ItemReplacementCode`. 
Since we are talking about one table:

- `ItemCode` is not a primary key
- `ItemReplacementCode` isn't foreign key.

They are just simply varchars columns.

What I would like to see in select result is:

```
id,     productname, itemcode, replacementCode
99,     dell ###,   a1234X,    null
10034,  dell ###,   1233bX,    a1234X
10024,  dell ###,   1232X,    1233bX
95,     dell ###,   999ws,    null
96,     sony ###,   327b,     null
```

and so on. Please note that `itemCode` and `replacementCode` aren't alphabetically friendly for sorting.

Can you guide me how to select products so they will be grouped and ordered by replacement code (please note, not grouped by scalar).
Certainly we are talking about kind of building graph of "relatives" retrieved by one sql statement among with "orphan" products which have no replacement.
Don't hesitate to ask for clarification.
References to similar discussions are appreciated.

I'm open to add additional hibernate relations only if they will not harm performance.

Comment: @RichardVivian : Thanks, I probably haven't raise attention enough by saying "(please note, not grouped by scalar)". What I need in result is selected products ordered by their replacement codes. I will try to update *question post* in a minute.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Hibernate?

Comment: I database engine is MsSQL, datalayer implemented on hibernate with xml mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of what you are looking for, but here are some options.

To just order by replacement code

```
SELECT id,     productname, itemcode, replacementCode
FROM ItemTable
ORDER BY replacementCode
```

I see that you have NULL values in the replacement code.   If you want to order by the Item, but use the replacement code if there is one try this

```
SELECT ISNULL(replacementCode ,itemcode) AS NewItemCode ,id, productname
FROM ItemTable
ORDER BY ISNULL(replacementCode ,itemcode)
```

Comment: 'Please note that itemCode and replacementCode aren't alphabetically friendly for sorting' eliminate 1st answer. 2nd sql-statement I have to read more carefully to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the sort of data result you are expecting to see?  That may help in understanding what you are looking for.Why not alphabetically friendly?

Comment: I'm out of idea how to properly answer questions here. Forgive for being short. Here is my attempt: "Can you post a sample of the sort of data result you are expecting to see?" - please see updated post question. "Why not alphabetically friendly?" ReplacementCode will not be follow the obvious rule. let's say there no such rule like "T5 replace T4" but it could be it could be "T5 replace W150".

Comment: I think my second option will give you what you are looking for.  It sounds like you want to sort by ItemCode, but If an item has been replaced, then by that replacement code not the original item code.

Comment: In 2nd statement operator ISNULL just replace not provided replacementCode with itemcode. And again statement does NOT build parent-child ordering. Probably the title of the question so misleading so folks keep answering about alphabetical ordering.